# script task using client.GetAsync(url) not waiting for a response

Tags: c#

I'm running a script task in ssis to call this API, but it's not waiting for a response before it finishes.  Is there something else I need to do?

```
public void Main()
{

    GetRequest(Dts.Variables["User::URL"].Value.ToString());
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}

private static void GetRequest(string url)
{
   try
   {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: " + e.Message);
   }
}
```

---

Tried this, but still not waiting:

```
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task MainAsync()
    {

        await GetRequestAsync(Dts.Variables["User::URL"].Value.ToString());
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    private static async Task GetRequestAsync(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you not get a response or does it never complete? i.e. is it hanging?

Comment: Are you certain it's not throwing an exception?

Comment: What is the exact behavior you are experiencing? What you get in the response? Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: When I call the API in a browser window it takes several seconds before it returns a message.  When I run the ssis package it completes a lot quicker.  So that's why I'm thinking it's not waiting for a response.

Comment: @rshiney How do you know that it's not waiting for a response? Adding a `Console.WriteLine()` would tell you.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, you'll want to mark the method as an async Task and then await the "client.GetAsync(url);" call

```
private static async Task GetRequestAsync(string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

On top of that, you can await the method specifically whenever it is called

Comment: While this is better design it would not change the overall outcome from OP's code that is forced to run synchronously.

Comment: OP's code doesn't explicitly tell the method to wait for the asynchronous call to complete

Comment: That is what `.Result` does.

Comment: Ideally, yes, but don't you have to account for having multiple threads? It may be made to run asynchronously but in a different thread which is essentially a synchronous call since the rest of the program continues to run in the original thread(s)

Comment: Not totally sure I get your meaning, but there is nothing async nor using other threads in OP's code.

Comment: Well yeah, OP's problem is that there is nothing explicitly async in their code, that's why I made it explicit... Is there a situation in which what I posted would be forced to run synchronously? if so, that may be causing OP's problem, if not then that code should fix their problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183213/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-giollia).

Comment: Suddenly I'm unable to access the chat. Not sure if it is SO or my network.

Comment: I see... I think you're right about SSIS (if there is a problem)
However, assuming both OP's code and my code would run asynchronously, how would OP's be less likely to continue than async code?

Comment: OP's code is synchronous because of the use of .Result. With async code you can forget to await which creates a fire-and-forget situation. But if you block with .Result (which you should try to avoid) it will run synchronously and cannot become fire-and-forget.

Comment: So that's more referring to writing async code in general, not specifically what i wrote. I get it, just as a personal preference, I think when writing new styles you should learn how to do it from scratch in case you ever run into a situation where you can't find what you want so you need to make it yourself. Properly written asynchronous code will never fire-and-forget

Comment: HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());  It looks like it is getting an error.  "Caught Exception: An error occurred while sending the request."